Not able to add a new server to NLB Cluster in Windows 2022
I setup an NLB Cluster with ARR and IIS Web Farm, here is my Setup:
Primary Site - 192.168.10.X (Primary Network) 192.168.200.X (Cluster Heartbeat)
2x NLB Servers
2x Web Servers for the server farm
Each web server has the same website for load balancing that has a URL mysite.mydomain.com and SSL certificate. I have created an A Route on Amazon Route 53 that points mysite.mydomain.com to the Cluster IP 192.168.10.X
Secondary Site (Different Location) - 192.168.20.X (Primary Network), 192.168.200.X (Cluster Heartbeat)
2x NLB Servers
2x Web Servers for the server farm
Each web server has the same website for load balancing as Primary Site which has a URL mysite.mydomain.com and SSL certificate. I used the same A record on route 53 and just added the cluster IP of the secondary servers
I was able to add the web servers to each of the farms without any issues but when I try to add the NLB servers from the primary site to the secondary cluster, it only shows me the heartbeat IP, not the dedicated IP, I tried searching by domain name or IP and get same results.
Even when I try to add the cluster IP as a secondary IP on the NLB manager, it doesn't work and I lose connectivity. Both sites have a Site-to-Site VPN between them and I can ping each server without any issues and they are all connected to the domain controller on the primary side.
I am stumped on how to connect. I also noticed when I check the monitoring on the Farm it shows the load is balanced across all servers in the farm on Primary side but secondary doesn't show anything. For the DNS since it has both IPs, it is random which IP it will get, so sometimes it might get the 10.X network, other times it will get 20.X.
